# how to make sure denormalized data insert into cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In Cassandra I have 4 tables having almost same ( duplication ) data. Pragmatically how can I make sure data inserted into 4 different table?

I am using NodeJS for my application server.

Answer (score 1):

Will batches help? [Cassandra BATCH](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logged batches.

You can follow the example using the Node.js driver for Cassandra:

```
var queries = [{
    query: 'UPDATE user_profiles SET email=? WHERE key=?',
    params: [emailAddress, 'hendrix']
  }, {
    query: 'INSERT INTO user_track (key, text, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
    params: ['hendrix', 'Changed email', new Date()]
}];
client.batch(queries, { prepare: true }, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('None of the changes were made');
    return;
  }
  console.log('All of the rows were updated/inserted');
});
```

Comment: If there is more than 1000's of query... 

For example I want to use feed, as soon as any person update their status all of their followers feed row must insert that value..

Comment: Then batches is not the way to go... batches are designed to be small sized.